# How can I import csv file with dynamic columns using codeigniter?

Tags: php, mysql, csv, codeigniter, import-from-excel

[This is My Csv File with three columns

```
user_id, Course_id and Marks
```

where all courses will be using course Id column in DB
This is My DB structure

[Where Course_id is Dynamic columns](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TpA6v.jpg)

Comment: [Search](https://duckduckgo.com/?t=ffab&q=codeigniter+import+csv&ia=web)

Comment: I'm not seeing your actual DB structure, just an Excel spread sheet, and because you say you have dynamic columns, I can assume that it isn't one-to-one since MySQL doesn't have dynamic columns. You will probably need to transform this to match your structure.